# Can I replace 45° elbows with 90° elbows in a vent stack?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I want to replace connection to the vertical stack with 2 x 90 deg connections versus the existing 2 x 45 deg connection. Is this acceptable to adjust for a spacing issue? Will it impact air flow, etc?

Comment: If the stack is a vent then it would be ok.  If it is for waste water no.

Comment: Remember that vents can get clogged too.

Answer (score 2):

Our inspector recommended (but did not insist on) replacing two 90° elbows in our vanity *drain* line with 45° elbows to improve water flow and reduce the chance of clogging. (One of the advantages of living in a small town - we got him to do a "pre inspection" prior to gluing everything up).

Since you've only got air (and, possibly some rainwater) running through the vent line, there should be no issue whatsoever with having two 90°s in the vent line instead of 45°s. So long as you can get it all to fit.

Also, be sure to have some slope in the "horizontal" run between the elbows in case some rain does get into the vent to enable it to flow out - you don't want it sitting stagnant. It may start to stink after a while and, after enough rain collects, it could block your vent completely if it's sloped incorrectly.

Comment: Keep in mind that vents can get clogged too.  Iin addition to that, main drains can be unclogged by running a snake down from the vent.

Answer (score 1):

Under IPC (and probably most other codes) vents **must run Vertical<sup>*</sup>** until they are **6" above the flood rim** of the **highest fixture on the floor served** by the vent. **[905.4](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P5/chapter-9-vents#IPC2018P5_Ch09_Sec905)**

<sup>*</sup>Vertical is defined as 45 to 90 degrees in this case.

That means you cannot turn vents horizontal (actually 2% slope to the drain side) until they are **6" above the flood rim** of the **highest fixture on the floor served** whatever that fixture is. It need not be a fixture in the same room.

So you can't turn 2 45s with a 45 sloped pipe in between to two 90s with a 2% sloped pipe in between them until you are above that level.

Comment: Good to know.  I guess the question needs more info.  The original didn't even address if it was a vent.